# How to edit comment reply link for specific content type in Drupal 7

Tags: comments, navigation

Is there a way I can programmatically edit comment reply links for a specific content type in Drupal 7?

So I need to check for the content type before changing the links:

```
<?php
if ($node->type == 'book') {
  // change comment reply links here
}
?>
```

Does anyone know how this can be achieved? Is there some sort of hook I need to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use preprocess comment function:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_comment(&$vars) {
  unset($vars['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-reply']);
}
```

Also check https://www.drupal.org/node/319298

Comment: Can I put this into my custom module?

Comment: yes, put it into your module and change MYTHEME_ to your module name. OR put this function into template.php and chnage to your theme name

Comment: Oh I see, how about if I want to change the href link instead of unsetting it?

Comment: try to debug $vars['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-reply'] , I guess it should contain 'href' attribute there